# Get Outlook To-Do-list using Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, outlook-2010

I am accessing Outlook with the [win32com module](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/docindex.html).

I want to get a hold of the task and flagged mails - Outlook has a lot of different names for them and look at them as to different type of "objects". However I want to get the list of Task Subjects and the due dates that appear when I press **Task/To-Do List** (Outlook 2010).

[image]

@utapyngo came up with a [very useful C# code example](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/06/12/outlook-tasks-create-get-delete/) - But I really need some help translating it to python.

```
Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
Outlook.MAPIFolder todoFolder = null;
Outlook.Items todoFolderItems = null;
Outlook.TaskItem task = null;
Outlook.ContactItem contact = null;
Outlook.MailItem email = null;
string todoString = string.Empty;

try
{
    ns = OutlookApp.Session;
    todoFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderToDo);
    todoFolderItems = todoFolder.Items;

    for (int i = 1; i <= todoFolderItems.Count; i++)
    {
        object outlookItem = todoFolderItems[i];
        if (outlookItem is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            email = outlookItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            todoString += String.Format("Email: {0} Due:{1}{2}",
                email.Subject, email.TaskDueDate, Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else if (outlookItem is Outlook.ContactItem)
        {
            contact = outlookItem as Outlook.ContactItem;
            todoString += String.Format("Contact: {0} Due:{1}{2}",
                contact.FullName, contact.TaskDueDate, Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else if (outlookItem is Outlook.TaskItem)
        {
            task = outlookItem as Outlook.TaskItem;
            todoString += String.Format("Task: {0} Due: {1}{2}",
                task.Subject, task.DueDate, Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown Item type");
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookItem);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(todoString);
}
finally
{
    if (todoFolderItems != null)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(todoFolderItems);
    if (todoFolder != null)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(todoFolder);
    if (ns != null)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here is an article](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/06/12/outlook-tasks-create-get-delete/.) that explains everything:

> It is easy to confuse a To-do item with a task, but bear in mind that a To-do item can either be an e-mail, contact or task. An Outlook item becomes a to-do item as soon as you flag it for follow-up. To get a list of to-do items use the Outlook Namespace object to get a reference to the default to-do folder. Be careful though, you need to check the type of the objects before accessing their properties!

It also has many examples in C#. If you have experience with win32com, you should be able to translate them into Python.

**EDIT**: Here is one of them translated:

```
import sys
import win32com.client

olFolderTodo = 28

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
todo_folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTodo)
todo_items = todo_folder.Items

def print_encoded(s):
    print s.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'replace')

for i in range(1, 1 + len(todo_items)):
    item = todo_items[i]
    if item.__class__.__name__ == '_MailItem':
        print_encoded(u'Email: {0}. Due: {1}'.format(item.Subject, item.TaskDueDate))
    elif item.__class__.__name__ == '_ContactItem':
        print_encoded(u'Contact: {0}. Due: {1}'.format(item.FullName, item.TaskDueDate))
    elif item.__class__.__name__ == '_TaskItem':
        print_encoded(u'Task: {0}. Due: {1}'.format(item.Subject, item.DueDate))
    else:
        print_encoded(u'Unknown Item type: {0}'.format(item))
```

**EDIT**: Fixed problems with encoding

Comment: I really like your answer, but find it very difficult translating C# code into python. win32com is very useful, but most admit that most of the time I don't see the logic but just like the result.

Comment: @Norfeldt, I have translated the example you asked for. Does it work for you?

Comment: How do I check if the task/todo is marked complete - because I just want a list of none complete tasks ?

Comment: I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 36: character maps to <undefined>` - I tried `print u'Email: {0}. Due: {1}'.format(item.Subject, item.TaskDueDate, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: This error occurs when console enconding does not have a unicode character that you want to display. I have edited my answer by adding the print_encoded() method which tries to encode a unicode string replacing unknown characters with a question mark.

Comment: Regarding your question about completed todo items, please read the Microsoft documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867891.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861252.aspx (search for "complete")

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38329/discussion-between-norfeldt-and-utapyngo)